# highcharts multiple marker hover color doesn't inherit from marker color

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I have highchart series data like this to have multiple dot on a column:

```
series: [{
      "marker": {
        "fillColor": "#69B0E0",
        "symbol": "circle"
      },
      "type": "line",
      "data": [
        6000,
        5500,
      ]
    },
    {
      "marker": {
        "fillColor": "#333f48",
        "symbol": "circle"
      },
      "type": "line",
      "data": [
        1000,
        4000,
      ]
    },
    {
      "marker": {
        "fillColor": "#b61f47",
        "symbol": "circle"
      },
      "type": "line",
      "data": [
        11000,
        3000,
      ]
    }
  ]
```

but when I hover it, the red radius color is green instead of red, but other 2 colors are fine, I wonder is this a bug on highcharts.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a0e9bz8k/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover color is inherited from `point.color` or `series.color`, so you need to set one of them.

```
    series: [...,
        {
            "marker": {
                "symbol": "circle"
            },
            color: "#b61f47",
            ...
        }
    ]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p0h6eqk3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.color